# Why is "Grab" so common in advertisments (and other places where it might not make much sense)?

Tags: word-usage, popularity

We area bombarded by advertisements which say "grab these offers NOW !" or "grab 2 @ 20% Discount or grab 3 @ 30% Discount !".

Dictionary meanings of Grab :

> - Take hold of so as to seize, restrain or stop the motion of
> - Get hold of or seize quickly and easily
> - Make a grasping or snatching motion with the hand
> - Obtain illegally or unscrupulously
> - Take or grasp suddenly

I am not sure if any of these meanings supports the advertisements.
It makes more sense to say "buy 2 @ 20% Discount or buy 3 @ 30% Discount !".

In other instances, I see examples like "grab the files from Bit-Torrent" or "Grab a Coke now". Files being virtual, why "grab" them ? We can drink Coke even by holding it normally, without grabbing it (from somebody else?) or snatching it.

Another Example is "screen capture" becoming "screen grabbing" where again, there may be better words to use.

> Why is grab so popular ?

Comment: Where are you? I don't see this very often where I am.

Comment: You ought to add a few examples to your question. I was a little skeptical until I Googled the phrase. Some of these are surely poor translations into English, like this one: _"So, never miss out to grab these offers now! At present, people are quite busy for engaging home and official works. They don’t have much time to have shopping with their families by visiting at local market."_ However, that may explain some of the hits, but it doesn't seem to explain every instance.

Comment: TLDR but I can't for the life of me see what's confusing about *grabbing* a good deal based on the definitions you posted.

Comment: When you buy something in the supermarket, you _grab_ it off the shelf with your hand and put it in your basket/trolley. From there, the metaphor just spread to places where you’re not literally grabbing anything with your hand, but there’s still a sense of snatching something quickly towards yourself because you want to be quick, before the brilliant offer runs out. Your second definition fits: “get hold of […] quickly and easily”. That’s **exactly** what ads want to communicate. I don’t quite see why this seems strange to you?

Comment: The word *grab* is meant to convey the idea of *eagerness*.  The ad wants you to feel eager about the product.  As a gesture, a "grab" is fairly rapid and indelicate; it represents an impulsive desire to have.

Comment: This is more a question about the psychology of bargain hunting than of language itself. But the general intention is always to create a sense of urgency and limited opportunity, thereby elevating the sense of achievement derived via the purchase.

Comment: Erm... links and references please.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , Initially I gave no references, but when asked, I added some. Now somebody said "TLDR", so I removed it. [http://thenextweb.com/offers/2014/11/28/come-get-grab-great-black-friday-offers-tnw-deals/ "Grab these great Black Friday offers from TNW Deals"] [https://www.facebook.com/Jlctanning/posts/744407435667078 "1 day to go to grab these great offers"] [https://twitter.com/gotoirelandgb/status/539373363911618560 "Grab these great offers for #Belfast!"] [http://www.mybullfrog.com/blog/grab-these-great-rebate-offers-from-mybullfrog/ "Grab these great rebate offers from Mybullfrog!"]

Comment: I would have liked a link to "*Grab a coke now!*" though! I'd go easy on the exclamation marks, proper ads in mags and TV v. rarely have more than one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , [https://www.happiness.coca-cola.com/uk/en/coke-zero/grab-a-coke-zero-wallpaper "Grab a Coke Zero wallpaper . . ."] [https://www.pinterest.com/azzybugs929/grab-a-coke/ "Grab a Coke . . "] [http://gossiponthis.com/2015/03/28/burger-king-chicken-fries-back-forever/ "grab a coke or sprite and bring your favorite . . ."] [http://www.awesomeocean.com/2015/02/27/grab-coke-find-whats-special-feb-27/ "Grab A Coke & Find Out . . ."] {I went overboard with the exclamation marks ; I will reduce that now}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to James McLeod & J.R. & George Pompidou & Janus Bahs Jacquet & Tim Romano , who were helpful with their comments.

It seems that advertisers wants customer to feel EAGER (subliminal suggestions ?) and buy it impulsively or quickly, so "grab this !!!!" is better than "buy this". There could be psychological factors involved.

There is also a valid usage of grab (get hold of easily and quickly), which has spread as a metaphor, to some other usages. Few folks may be using it as a cliche or fashionable word for "buy". A variant is "up for grabs", which means "available for anyone; not yet claimed" and probably represents throwing something up in the air so that anybody can reach out and grab it.

Beyond these, there is also the case of improper usage, due to bad translations.

I am making this a community wiki, so other folks can add relevant points.

Comment: I agree that it urges consumers to buy impulsively or quickly. I imagine they use "grab" for the same reason that infomercials urge you to "call now!"

Answer (score 0):

Advertisements typically use what they believe will attract more customers, rather than worrying about whether they're using the words correctly.

According to one of your definitions:
- Get hold of or seize quickly and easily

This definition doesn't necessitate that the thing you're seizing has to be physical, or that you have to physically grab it with your hand.